# 45-45-90 Triangles and the Relation to Circles.

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

So, The other day I was playing around with Geogabra, as one does, when I made a discovery I couldn't find elsewhere. I found that if you have 45-45-90 special right triangles within a circle, you can do some math to find the area of the circle if your only given the area of the triangle, and vice-versa. This is already somewhat easy if you know basic algebra, but there is a way to do it by just multipling and dividing one time. Let me explain.

If you have an image like this, where the triangle within it is a 45-45-90 triangle, and the congrent sides are equivelent to the radius of the circle. (The areas are already filled in for easyness sake):
[Image for Example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bFpQ.png)

You can find the area of the circle if you're given the area of the triangle by multipling the area of the triangle by 2(pi).

The example given in the image, the area of the triangle is 50, so 50*pi = about 314.16, which is about the area of the circle. Dividing the area of the cricle by 2(pi) would give you 50, the area of the triangle.

You can do something similar with a 45-45-90 triangle, but the hypotenuse is equal to the diameter of the circle: [Image 2 for Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRWaL.png)

to solve this, simple multiply the area of the triangle, in this case 100, by pi to get the circle's area, or divide the area of the circle by pi to get the triangle's area.

This works for any triangle/circle combonation that follow these rules:

1. The triangle is 45-45-90
2. Either the hypotenuse is equal to the circle's diameter, or the other two sides are both equal to the circle's radius.

I hope you enjoyed this math jargin. My question is: is this an actal thing that already exists and people know about, or is it something that I discovered? I dought that, but hey, it's worth a shot. I'm asking because I'm currently taking geometry, and we are long past our special right triangle unit, but I have never heard of this before. Thanks for coming to my Ted Talk.

Comment: Yes I made an account just to ask that.

Comment: It can be proven using a few lines of algebra.

Comment: That's just a geometric way of sayng that the area of a circle is $\pi r^2$ in both cases : four triangles makes a square in the first case, and two triangles in the second

Comment: I applaud you on spotting a pattern like this and investigating it further without prompting and without knowing ahead of time whether or not it was already known.  Unfortunately, it is exceedingly rare for a result of this level to have not already been discovered several centuries ago.  Still, it is great to be able to say you figured something out like this on your own, even if it was already done before you.  Keep it up, and I hope you have continued success.

Comment: Ahhh, I get it. Thanks everyone. Thanks G Cab for explainin the part about the four trignales, but i didn't realize that part, i did know the two triangles part. JMoravitz, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: It reminds me of a more general problem, the [dissection of a triangle into similar triangles](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220452374_Dissection_of_a_Triangle_into_Similar_Triangles) (jump first to the figures at the end)